# How to make a dialog show show all the text fields using only XML?

Tags: android, android-layout

I have an activity with style Dialog, containing two EditTexts. However, only the first one is shown when I run the app. Here is my code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:background="@color/background"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:padding="10dip" >

<EditText
        android:id="@+id/firstEditText"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:lines="1"
        android:inputType="number"
        android:scrollHorizontally="false"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"/>

<EditText
        android:id="@+id/secondEditText"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:lines="3"
        android:scrollHorizontally="false"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

As far as I know, this is normal Android behavior, but how can I make the activity show both fields without writing Java code and using only XML?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second `EditText` doesn't appear because the parent `LinearLayout` has the default orientation(`horizontal`) and the first `EditText` has the width set to `fill_parent`. This will push the second `EditText` out of the screen. You either set the orientation of the `LinearLayout` to `vertical` to show the `EditText` one below the other or you set `wrap_content` as the width for the first `EditText` and use `layout_weight`(on both `EditText`) to set up a desired ration between the first and second `EditText`.

Answer (score 1):

just add one line android:orientation="vertical"

```
     <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
      android:layout_height="fill_parent"
      android:padding="10dip"
      android:orientation="vertical" >
```

this should work fine i hope!!!!

Answer (score 1):

try this in place of your code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
         android:background="@color/background"
         android:layout_width="fill_parent"
         android:layout_height="fill_parent"
         android:padding="10dp" 
         android:orientation="vertical">

  <EditText
    android:id="@+id/firstEditText"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:lines="1"
    android:inputType="number"
    android:scrollHorizontally="false"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"/>

  <EditText
    android:id="@+id/secondEditText"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:lines="3"
    android:scrollHorizontally="false"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score -1):

In this case you can use the attribute in particular component...

```
android:visibility="gone"
```

it maybe helpful for you...

Comment: This causes the element to become hidden, which is the opposite of what I'm trying to do.